# How to debug python called by local process?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Hi I'm trying to debug python script called from another process, thus I would need to attach it to the process.

I actually read this [doc](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_remote-debugging) and I'm struggling at the "Attach to a local script" part.

It is said that I should:

1. In the terminal, start Python with the script
2. Switch to the Debug view, select Python: Attach

However, it does not give out the detail in launch.json.

Furthermore, it is not clear that which file I should start or stop. To me it seems like I should start the script in command line and restart it in debugger.

---

So what I would like to do is to debug a python script called from excel, the VBA codes are as follow

```
Sub Button1_Click()
RunPython("import Test; Test.testprint")
End Sub
```

The call is through xlwings add-in.

And in Test.py:

```
def testprint()
    print("abcd\n")
```

This is a test script, the actual script would try to do some file operations. But what I really like to do is enabling debug from a call from Excel-VBA.

Thus, would I please have an example of launch.json, script and detailed operation steps. Thanks a lot.

My platform:

OS:       Windows 10,
Editor:   VS-Code,
Python:   3.6.5,
Anaconda: 4.5.4,
ptvsd:    5.0.0a4

I've been struggling with it for whole day. Thanks to anyone who could help.

Comment: Make sure you actually call the function with `Test.testprint()`. Then try debugging it with https://github.com/alexmojaki/birdseye. With that you don't have to attach to the process, just decorate the function with `@eye` and view the results in a browser.

Comment: Hi I'm in company environment, internet and installation is extremely limited.......